# Translation and context of 'faciam ut potero'

Tags: classical-latin, ovidius, motto

What is the most accurate translation to English of this expression

> FACIAM UT POTERO

I think this appears in some Ovidius's poem and is a motto of an school of lawyers in Spain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would translate that as "I will do as I can".
Perhaps "I will do all I can" or "I will do as well as I can" would be more idiomatic English, albeit less direct.

You have two verbs in future tense: *faciam* (I will do) and *potero* (I will be able to).
Between then is *ut*, which has a number of meanings.
The meaning intended here seems to be that of a relative adverb (see [the entry L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=ut&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), meaning I.B).
In this use it is essentially synonymous with *eo modo quo*, and I translated it as "as".

It seems that Ovidius used *potero* [five times](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=potero+%5Bov%5D), none of which matches the motto.
Instead, the phrase seems to be from Cicero's *Cato Maior de Senectute*, [paragraph 7](http://thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/senectute.shtml#7).